# MIPS memory model: Compiling software to run in KSEG0 or KSEG1

Tags: kernel, mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

In the MIPS memory model both KSEG0 and KSEG1 map to the same physical addresses but KSEG1 is uncached while KSEG0 is cached. The argument for this is that you can dynamically decide to run code either Cached or Uncached.

My question is: how do you actually compile code which runs in either virtual address space and how do you switch between them? Example, jump addresses are still hardcoded.

The only thing I can think of is using position independent code but it doesn't appear that you can use a hardware switch to change if you jump into KSEG0 or KSEG1. I suppose you could write your software to run in KSEG0 or KSEG1 and then add conditional jumps to the labels + offset which are needed to push your code into KSEG0 or KSEG1 region.

Any ideas?